# Undefined Variable Multiple Query Scopes Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This work perfect:

```
public function scopeHBO($query)
{
    return $query ->where('network', '=', "hbo");

}
```

Call in Controller: It Works!

```
$events = Schedule::HBO()->orderBy('searchdate')->get();
```

When I add another Query Scope like so:

```
 public function scopeHBO($query)
{
    return $query
            ->where('network', '=', "hbo")
            ->where('searchdate', '>=', 'NOW()');
}
```

OR:

```
public function scopeDate($query)
{
    return $query->where('searchdate', '>= ', 'NOW()');
}
```

Then call in the controller:

```
$events = Schedule::HBO()->Date()->orderBy('searchdate')->get();
```

I get an error: Undefined variable: event. I tried with with Raw MySql in the same model and it works. Whenever i add a query scope, does not matter what it is.. i get that same error Undefined variable: event.

Comment: None of the code shown would cause `Undefined variable: event`.

Comment: No where in there are you using a variable named `event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOW()` is a function, so you need to use a raw query:

```
where('searchdate', '>=', DB::raw('NOW()'))
```

Then you can use the scopes. (Do note that I think `scopeDate` must be called as `date()`, not `Date()` - not 100 % sure on that though.)

Comment: This Worked... Thank you:    return $query ->where('searchdate', '>=', DB::raw('NOW()'));

Answer (score 0):

This sounds less like a generic problem with Laravel, and more like a problem with you specific application.

My guess (which is a wild guess), is that adding that second where clause in your scope method

```
return $query
        ->where('network', '=', "hbo")
        ->where('searchdate', '>=', 'NOW()');
```

ended up creating a SQL query that returned 0 rows.  Then, somewhere in your other code you're doing something like

```
foreach($events as $event)
{
    //...
}

//referencing final $event outside of loop
if($event) { ... }
```

As I said, this is a wild guess, but the problem doesn't seem to be your query code, the problem seems to be the rest of your code that relies on the query returning a certain number of, or certain specific, rows/objects.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing in the view. It works just fine without the additional query scope. I think i was writing the added query scope wrong as what nhbjgfcxhgchg suggested worked.